# How to Convert 1h 47m to Time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, type-conversion

My version of management studio is 2017.

I've been given some really poor data which unfortunately is un-modifiable at source so I have to deal with what's in front of me.

Basically I have a column called **Time**, with values such as these in it:

**Time**

```
1h 51
1h 47m
2h 26m
41m
38m
```

How can I convert these values to look like the following?

**Time**

```
01:51:00
01:47:00
02:26:00
00:41:00
00:38:00
```

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I've not found an example of conversion for formats like this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Fyi *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* is a client tool, not the RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the sample data provided does the following work for you?

```
with t as (
 select '1h 51' t union all
 select '1h 47m' union all
 select '2h 26m' union all
 select '41m' union all
 select '38m' 
)
select *, 
    Try_Convert(time,Replace(case when t like '%h%' then Replace(t,'h',':') else concat('0:',t) end,'m','')) TimeValue
from t
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick, thanks so much! Once again I sincerely apologise if this question has been asked before.